# scalar curve node

Tags: node-editor

There exists the "Vector Curves" node.
I can nicely map the $x,y,z$ components of a vector with domain and range $[-1,1]$ using this node.
However I do not always need a vector, sometimes I only want to create a curve for a scalar.
The "Map range" and "ColorRamp" are the nodes that are closest to this, but:

- "Map range" doesn't allow nearly as much freedom
- "ColorRamp" assumes values in $[0,1]$

Is there a node like the vector-curves, but only for a scalar?
If not, I would be interested if anyone has some workaround (I could imagine a group, where the input is first mapped from $[-1,1]$ to $[0,1]$, and the output is mapped from $[0,1]$ to $[-1,1]$ again, but I am open to alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use separate XYZ and combine XYZ Nodes to separate the vector into its scalars or create a vector out of 1, 2 or 3 Scalars.

Does that work for your case?

Comment: I guess that's what i'm going to do, thank you! A bit cumbersome, considering there could just be a scalar curve node, but yes, it does the job!